# Solr doesn't work on partial search

Tags: python, solr

I have the following data into solr:

[image: Solr structure]

With this Schema.xml config:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="Titulo" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="Anio" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="ISBN" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="URL" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="Autor" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" />
```

but I can not do partial matches, only with the full string (for example, I have to put all the URL to search by that field). How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below field type in your schema.xml.
Use the "partial_search" fieldType for your field(s) where you want to perform the partial search.

Once you are done with schema.xml changes, you need to do the restart the server ans re-index the data.

```
<fieldType name="partial_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i'm getting this error:  Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "partial_search": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: The schema defines multiple tokenizers for: [tokenizer: null].

Comment: I make it work deleting this <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>